# How to deflate a TypedArray uzing zlib in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib, typed-arrays

For some Int32Array `a`, I have tried this:

```
var d = zlib.deflateSync(new Buffer(a));
```

But when I do

```
var b = new Int32Array(zlib.inflateSync(d));
```

I get `b` which is different than `a`.

I am aware of idea of turning the array into a string before deflating. This is just not memory efficient.

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: It works for me with node v5 at least: `new Int32Array(zlib.inflateSync(zlib.deflateSync(new Buffer(new Int32Array(new Buffer('hello'))))))`

Comment: This doesn't work: `new Int32Array(zlib.inflateSync(zlib.deflateSync(new Buffer(new Int32Array([2,-2,257])))))`

Comment: I think that is expected. `Buffer` stores its byte values as unsigned 8-bit integers.

Comment: Yes, it is expected. That is why I don't know how to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is not in deflating and inflating, as those two actions just transfer data from one `Buffer` element to another `Buffer` element, and vice versa, as expected. Problem here is how to transfer typed array (e.g. `Int32Array`) to `Buffer`, and from `Buffer` back to typed array. To do that we have to deal with `Buffer`, `ArrayBuffer`, and typed arrays here.

Let's have `Int32Array` `a` to start with:

```
var a = new Int32Array([3,-2,258]);
```

If you create a `Buffer` from this typed array directly with `var b = new Buffer(b);`, you will get a buffer which contain 3 bytes instead of 12 (each element in `Int32Array` has 4 bytes), which means you will lose some information. The right way to do this is to create `Buffer` from `ArrayBuffer`. You can do it like so:

```
var b = new Buffer(a.buffer);
```

That way you get a `Buffer` which contains 12 bytes. Now it is easy to deflate and inflate this buffer `b`:

```
var c = zlib.deflateSync(b);
var d = zlib.inflateSync(c);
```

Now buffers `d` and `b` contain the same elements. Nothing special about this.

Now if you create `Int32Array` directly from `Buffer` `d`, you will get 4 times more elements that you should because each byte in the `Buffer` `d` will be mapped to one element in `Int32Array`. To overcome this problem, we will use `Uint8Array`:

```
var e = new Uint8Array(d);
```

We used `Uint8Array` just to map each byte of the buffer `d` to one byte of an typed array of which we now have access to its `ArrayBuffer`. The last step is to create the final `Int32Array` from `ArrayBuffer` of typed array `e`:

```
var f = new Int32Array(e.buffer);
```

Finally we have `f` that looks the same as `a`.

Note that some steps above depend on [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If you do all this on the same machine you should be fine with the steps above.